# Converting all values (in feet) in a column (field) to metric for a data set

Tags: sql, sql-server

"From" field is entered in feet but want to convert it to meters
Table: Mileage
Fields: From, Length

```
UPDATE Mileage
SET 
    ROUND(From/2.2808,2)
WHERE
    Length >= 1
```

Comment: So whats the question? The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) tell you how to complete your update statement.

Comment: Have you try your solution ? It works ... or not ? Can you remove that you are new from title ?

Answer (score 0):

In an `update` statement, you need to `set` the value.  `from` is a really, really bad name for a column, because it is a SQL keyword.  But you can do:

```
UPDATE Mileage
    SET [from] = ROUND([From/2.2808],2)
    WHERE Length >= 1;
```